# How did the artist make this?

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, color

https://sketchfab.com/models/cd8a494b42104a538f6b948ba92b73c9?ref=related

-How are the colors faded in that way?

-How was the glass made; how is the blue and white stuff perfectly see-through when look at it straight. How did the white contour of the bottle get there.

I'm in the process of learning more Blender and this bottle is just so awesome.

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Comment: Cycles, Internal, external, or what? This isn't really complicated stuff, most of this question falls under texture painting anyway.

Comment: This is super basic stuff, I think you should maybe try getting a better understanding of the software before shooting too high. If you want to go for it, take a look at gradient textures and object mapping. This question is also not very useful for other users down the line as is, you may want to make it better in order to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How are the colors faded in that way?

I'm guessing you're talking about the vertical gradient, which, can be derived from a program like [handplane](http://www.handplane3d.com/). Then, you can color it in a photo editing software such as [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) through color multiplication.

> How was the glass made

If you are using software like Unreal, Cycles, Blender, etc, you can use a Fresnel function with a sharp falloff and a blue gradient. This will round the corners however, and if you want to perfectly duplicate the bottle, you will have to have two models: one for the inside and one for the outside of the bottle, colored accordingly(You can easily do this with a thickness modifier, then separate the parts manually). Then, draw the inside over the outside with [this method](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92802/force-draw-objects-in-front-of-others).

> I'm in the process of learning more Blender

As am I. Welcome to the community!